# making the Paging Footer in asp:datagrid to come on the footer of the grid irrespective of the grid size

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I am new to asp.net. I have a problem with the **asp:datagrid**.
The grid comes with the Paging Footer *PagerStyle* always at the bottom of the grid. I would like the *PagerStyle* to be fixed at the footer of the **asp:datagrid**.

My Current code

```
 <asp:datagrid id="grdPageTemplate">
<!-- Code to make the columns of my grid-->
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Mode="NumericPages" Position="Bottom" CssClass="footer"></PagerStyle>
```

I have tried to make a CSS class to do so but it does not work that way. Please help me out.

The CSS class I am using

```
footer{background-color:#C0C0C0;position:fixed;height:100px;width: 100%;top:100%;margin-top: -100px;}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP. Please retag.

Answer (score 0):

@vaibhav.pnd kindly post your full asp:datagrid code.
Mean while, For only pager, use the below attributes along with your code.

```
<asp:datagrid ID="grdPageTemplate" runat="server" Width="100%" ShowFooter="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10">
    <!-- Code to make the columns of my grid-->
    <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
    </asp:datagrid>
```